# How to write a recursion function

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to write a function that like :

```
List<Point>points=FindPoints(allPoints,point);
for(int i=0;i<points.Count;i++){
    List<Point>nextPoints=FindPoints(allPoints,points[i]);
    for(int j=0;j<nextPoints.Count;j++){

........
   }
}
```

How to write it in a recursion?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to recurse, you have to put the core of the code into a functon which then calls itself, so:

```
List<Point> RecursiveFindPoints(List<Point> allPoints, Point point)
{
    List<Point> result = new List<Point>();
    List<Point> points = FindPoints(allPoints,point);
    result.AddRange(points);
    for(int i=0;i<points.Count;i++)
    {
        result.AddRange(RecursiveFindPoints(allPoints,points[i]));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Updated answer to new requirement